# How to count selected days in react-native-calendars?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-calendars

I have an issue. For my react-native project I use react-native-calendars, I need to be able to count number of selected days in calendar. I read docs for this library, but I don't found the solution.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a onDayPress that you can implement

```
<CalendarList
onDayPress={(day) => {console.log('push day to array')}} />
```